# Concatenating Items In A Collection

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I have a `SearchResultCollection` from ActiveDirectory called `$results`:

```
$results = $directorySearcher.FindAll()
```

There are two `SearchResult` objects in that collection representing computers.
I want to have a string with the computer names separated by commas:

```
$computerNames = $results | Select-Object { $_.Properties.name }
$computerNamesCommaSeparated = $computerNames -join ","
```

However this gives me just `","` with no computer names inside it.

I can see in `$computerNames` that it has the following:

```
$_.Properties.name
------------------
ComputerName1
ComputerName2
```

How can I get this to work?

Comment: `$ComputerNames.Properties.name -join ","` or instead `$computerNames = $results | ForEach-Object { $_.Properties.name }` then join.

Comment: That works. Thankyou.

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler why not write an answer instead of a comment so I can mark it as the accepted answer?

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```
$computerNamesCommaSeparated = $results.Properties.name -join ","
```

Comment: always stupid man which down vote without explain, this code work!

Comment: I think your code won't work because the Properties property is present only on each element in $results, not on the $results object itself.

Comment: this code work, i have tested... Verify your affirmation before... Try by example this code "(get-childitem -recurse).FullName"